# error message showing in all div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

js:

```
var KEYS = {
    SPACE: 32
};
$(".trim-space").keyup(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val($.trim($this.val()));
    if (e.keyCode == KEYS.SPACE) {
        $(".errorlist").show();
        $(".errorlist").text("No space please");
    }
});
```

my html:

```
<tr>
    <td>Daytime phone:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="trim-space" name="phone_daytime" />
        <div style="display:none" class="errorlist">No space please</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Mobile phone:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="trim-space" name="phone_mobile" />
        <div style="display:none" class="errorlist">No space please</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In my application,there are six fields with same class name to validate space.I am showing the error message via a hidden div,which is also having the same class.These divs are inside a table's `<td>` tag.

My problem is if i press the space bar,it is showing the error message but it is showing in all div.I want to show the error message for the which input field the space bar is press.How to do this.

Comment: can you provide more of your html?

Comment: Create an `.each();` loop for the items you want to validate, then use `$(this)` to specify which one you want it to show the error for.

Comment: And you're not using id because?

Comment: You should try to target the exact element you want to show. Get an identifier of the input field that triggered the event, and then show _only_ what you need to show...

Comment: How are the `.trim-space` fields related to the `.errorlist` DIVs? Where are they in the HTML you showed?

Comment: show where you are using `.trim-space` in html

Comment: This should work: `$(this).parent().children('.errorlist').show()`

Comment: So what you want is validation, then... [Look what i found](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this.siblings(".errorlist").text("No space please").show();
```

See the documentation [`jQuery.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: Could you please share the document related to this answer for future reference.

Comment: Added a documentation link

Answer (score 1):

use  .closest to show the closet div only.

```
$this.closest($(".errorlist")).show();
$this.closest($(".errorlist")).text("No space please");
```

Comment: `.closest()` will only work if the `.errorlist` DIV contains the `.trim-space` DIV, which is unlikely.

Comment: @user2681579 The general idea of this answer is right. You just need to use the correct jQuery Traversal functions to get from `$this` to the associated `.errorlist` DIV. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/. We can't answer more specifically because you haven't shown all the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Set ID for each element as ID is to identify the unique element on a page:

```
<div style="display:none" id="nameField" class="errorlist">No space please</div>
```

and then:

```
$("#nameField").text("No space please");
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var KEYS = { SPACE: 32 };
    $(".trim-space").keyup(function(e) {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.val($.trim($this.val()));

      if (e.keyCode == KEYS.SPACE) {

          $this.next(".errorlist").text("No space please").show(); 
     }
     else{

          $this.next(".errorlist").hide();
     }
 });
```